# Zelle graphics: Access and Manipulate Display Buffer?

Tags: python, buffer, display, zelle-graphics

I am doing 2D graphics using `graphics.py`. I wonder if there is a way I can access the display buffer after all the 2D geometries are drawn and before they show up on display. I need to do a post process on the drawn image.  For example, tasks I am planning include anti-aliasing for a smoother transition on the edge and applying a geometry warp map for a correct projection on a curved screen, etc.  Can anyone tell me how to access the display buffer?  If I have to go down to tkinter Canvas, will it work and how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. per [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/5.0.1.post1/#files) "John Zelles graphics.py package, for use with the textbook "Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science". Providing help is easiest when code illustrating a specific issue is provided. Code for a question is known as a **Minimal, Reproducible Exampl(MRE)**.  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provides information to help develop an MRE. That can be challenging.

Comment: I don't think you understand how Zelle's `graphics` module creates what gets displayed on the screen. Underneath the covers it's drawing everything onto a `tkinter` `Canvas` widget whose internal buffer is generally not directly accessible — although I believe there are ways to get a *copy* of it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: as I know you can't access buffer. You should use `pygame` instead of `graphics` and `tkinter`. In Pygame you draw on surface(s) and later you send it to screen - so you can modify surfaces.